# Alternative to vs-repeat fro virtual scrolling

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, virtualization

I try vs-repeat from https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat for virtual scrolling, but need a better performance. Do you know any alternative...